# TIME_CREATE return EAGAIN, but resource is sufficient

Tags: c, linux

Code is like this.In some situation, eagain is returned.

```
struct sigevent sev;
sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD_ID;
sev._sigev_un._tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
sev.sigev_signo = alarm_signal();
r = timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &sev, &_steady_clock_timer);
assert(r >= 0);
```

In the man, EGAIN is returned in two situation,

```
EAGAIN
The system lacks sufficient signal queuing resources to honor the request.
EAGAIN
The calling process has already created all of the timers it is allowed by 
this implementation.
```

the first situation, in our machine, ulimit -i is 2061776, it can not reach this limit.

What is the timer limit said by the second situation and how to find it?

Comment: The [manual page for `timer_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) actually says "Temporary error during kernel allocation of timer structures." so maybe you need to retry or check your arguments. `_steady_clock_timer` is not shown here and might not be properly initialized.

Comment: `_steady_clock_timer` is defined as `timer_t _steady_clock_timer = {}`

Comment: Is that sufficient to initialize all the internal properties?

Comment: resource is sufficient. It doesn't happen all the time, just happen in some machines

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the `EAGAIN` case here.

`timer_create()`'s implementation does two allocation during system call handling. It could happen in cases if a) timer allocation or b) sigqueue allocation failure.

Another things to look at is finding the running task's `sigpending` size. It is possible to increase the running task's `RLIMIT_SIGPENDING` (`man setrlimit`). Changing with `ulimit` will affect only to the shell and the process started by it, therefore it might have no direct impact on your application.

Comment: i'll try to add some log and retry when eagain appeared

Answer (score 0):

Try making the following change:

```
struct sigevent sev;
memset(&sev, 0, sizeof(sev));
```

It is possible that there's an aspect of `sigevent` that gets initialized to something that breaks the timer allocation.